# Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\frac n2$ is a perfect square, $\frac n3$ is a perfect cube and $\frac n5$ is a perfect 5th power.

Tags: number-theory

I was able to solve this question but I am looking for a method to solve such questions with shortcut or a shorter method than the following
Consider,

$n =  (2^a)(3^b)(5^c)(p_4^d)(p_5^e)\ldots(p_k^k)$ be its unique factorization ($p_4, p_5, \ldots, p_k$ are all primes other than $2, 3, 5$)

now,

$$
\frac n2 = [2^{a-1}](3^b)(5^c)(p_4^d)(p_5^e)\ldots(p_k^k)\\
\frac n3 = (2^a)[3^{b-1}](5^c)(p_4^d)(p_5^e)\ldots(p_k^k)\\ 
\frac n5 = (2^a)(3^b)[5^{c-1}](p_4^d)(p_5^e)\ldots(p_k^k) 
$$
according to conditions

$$
a = 2q + 1 = 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,\ldots\\
a = 3r = 0,3,6,9,12,15,\ldots\\
a = 5s = 0,5,10,15,\ldots\\
\min(a) = 15\\
\\
b = 2q = 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,\ldots\\
b = 3r + 1 = 1,4,7,10,\ldots\\
b = 5s = 0,5,10,15,\ldots\\
\min(b) = 10\\
\\
c = 2q = 0,2,4,6,8,10,\ldots\\
c = 3r = 0,3,6,\ldots\\
c = 5s + 1 = 1,6,\ldots\\
\min(c) = 6
$$

the min common values for $d,e,f,\ldots, k = 0$ therefore $p_4, p_5, \ldots, p_k$ all are equal to $1$.

Hence the required number is $(2^{15})(3^{10})(5^6)$.

Comment: You can learn matjax from here,which makes equations look clear http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What you're doing seems to be the straightforward direct way of solving this, and I can't see anything easier being available. Your final computation of each of $a, b,c$ could be dignified slightly by calling each of them an application of the _Chinese Remainder Theorem_, but that's about it.

Comment: There are so many places where this problem has been solved using your method(by Google Search) and you have asked for a better solution. Very disappointing.